# Displaying a single row in codeigniter integrated with facebox

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebox

I've been using facebox recently and it's okay. But when i got to use it with codeigniter, its so hard for me. In this code that i put in codeigniter:

```
<a rel="facebox" href="<?php echo site_url('logincon/vieworders/');?>">View Orders</a>
```

I aim to pass it with specific id, like this code below which is not working in CI:

```
<a rel="facebox" href="echo site_url('logincon/vieworders'))" id='.$row['reservation_id'].' title="Click To View Orders">View Orders</a>
```

Which is which?

Here's my codes:

In my controller:

```
public function vieworders()
 {  
    // $this->data['date'] = $this->loginmod->getdate();
     $data['date'] = $this->loginmod->getdate();
     $data['name'] = $this->loginmod->getimage();
     $data['order'] = $this->loginmod->getorderdetail();
     $data['reservation'] = $this->loginmod->getdesign();

     $this->load->view('vieworders', $data);

 }
```

In my model:

```
public function getdate(){
$q=$this->db->get('orders_date');
if($q->num_rows()>0){
return $q->result_array();
}
}
public function getimage() {
    $query = $this->db->get("image");
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
    return $query->result_array();
}
}
public function getorderdetail() {
    $query = $this->db->get("order_detail");
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
    return $query->result_array();
}
}
public function getdesign()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('reservation');
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
    return $query->result_array();
}
}
```

And in my view:

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="resultTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th  style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7">Order Date </th>
        <th>Photo size </th>
        <th> Quantity </th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="record">
        <?php foreach ($date as $da) { ?>
         <td><div align="left"><?php echo $da['date']; ?></div></td>
        <?php } ?> 

        <?php foreach ($name as $images) { ?>
        <td style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;"><?php echo $images['name']; ?> </td>
        <?php } ?> 

        <?php foreach ($order as $detail) { ?>
        <td><?php
            echo $detail['quantity'];?></td>    
        <?php } ?> 
</tr>
</tbody>
```

The output of these, it shows all the date,name and quantity that are in the database. Thats my problem, I only want a single row or only one output each query.

Comment: tell me what exactly you need? do you want to select data from multiple table on a condition and than fetch them as a single row do you want to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i am seeing the method you are using is difficult to maintain when you goes deeper in your project because of creating a function for every table in model file is not a good idea it's gona be time consuming what if you write generic function which better work and easily memorize able.
Now coming to the point you have created four functions and i am going to create two generic function instead of making four and it will be valuable in your project and also will solve your problem as well .

1. ***Model***

***Function for returning single row data***

```
function get_record($table, $where=NULL)
        {
            if(!empty($where))
            {
                $this->db->where($where);
            }
            $query=$this->db->get($table);
            if($query->num_rows>0)
            {
                return $query->row();
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
```

***Function for returning multiple rows data***

```
function get_records($table, $where=NULL)
    {
        if(!empty($where))
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        $query=$this->db->get($table);
        if($query->num_rows>0)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return array();
        }
    }
```

2. ***Controller***

Now its depends upon you weather to take resultset(full records) or either select only one row see how easy it is.

***For single results***

```
     $data['date'] = $this->loginmod->get_record('orders_date');
     $data['name'] = $this->loginmod->get_record('image');
     $data['order'] = $this->loginmod->get_record('order_detail');
     $data['reservation'] = $this->loginmod->get_record('reservation');
```

***Now for multiple records***

```
    $data['date'] = $this->loginmod->get_records('orders_date');
     $data['name'] = $this->loginmod->get_records('image');
     $data['order'] = $this->loginmod->get_records('order_detail');
     $data['reservation'] = $this->loginmod->get_records('reservation');
```

***View***

*This is for multiple records if you have use get_records function so you have to use foreach to loop through every result and display it here*

```
<tr class="record">
        <?php foreach ($date as $da) { ?>
         <td><div align="left"><?php echo $da->date; ?></div></td>
        <?php } ?> 

        <?php foreach ($name as $images) { ?>
        <td style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;"><?php echo $images->name; ?> </td>
        <?php } ?> 

        <?php foreach ($order as $detail) { ?>
        <td><?php
            echo $detail->quantity;?></td>    
        <?php } ?> 
      <?php foreach ($reservation as $row) { ?>
       <td>
<a rel="facebox" href="<?=site_url('logincon/vieworders')?>" id='<?=$row['reservation_id']?>' title="Click To View Orders">View Orders</a>
        </td>  
       <?php } ?>   
</tr>
```

But if you have used get_record function you no longer need foreach loop just verify on if(isset()) and echo out the column.

```
    <?php if(isset($name)) { ?>
    <td style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;"><?php echo $name['name']; ?> </td>
    <?php } ?> 

    <?php if(isset($order)) { ?>
    <td><?php
        echo $order['quantity'];?></td>    
    <?php } ?>



    <?php if(isset($reservation)) { ?>
        <td>
<a rel="facebox" href="<?=site_url('logincon/vieworders')?>" id='<?=$row['reservation_id']?>' title="Click To View Orders">View Orders</a>
        </td>    
        <?php } ?>
```

I hope this will help you alot in your project as well as clear your concept about creating generic functions instead of creating function for every different table.

Comment: just add these both function as at is in your model and than after add the code as i givin controller section if you want single result copy the single controller data into controller and the rest for view

Comment: i have gave a brief description start from model copy the both function in your model

Comment: than come to controller now it depands upon you weather to copy for single record or multiple records select one plan for controller and if you select single record than come to the view copy the data for which is the last code i hope it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Your database tables should be connected.

example:
1) reservation(rervation_id, name, ...)
2) orders_date(date_id, reservation_id, ...)
3) image(image_id, reservation_id, ...)
4) order_detail(detail_id, reservation_id, ...)

```
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" id="resultTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th  style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7">Order Date </th>
        <th>Photo size </th>
        <th> Quantity </th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="record">
        <?php

        if ( @$reservations )
        {
            foreach ( $reservations as $reservation )
            {
                $reservation_date = $reservation_image = $reservation_detail = "";

                if ( @$dates )
                {
                    foreach ( $dates as $date )
                    {
                        if ( $date->reservation_id == $reservation->reservation_id )
                        {
                            $reservation_date = $date->name...(or anything)
                        }
                    }
                }   

                if ( @$images )
                {
                    foreach ( $images as $image )
                    {
                        if ( $image->reservation_id == $reservation->reservation_id )
                        {
                            $reservation_image = $images->name...(or anything)
                        }
                    }
                }           

                if ( @$details )
                {
                    foreach ( $details as $detail )
                    {
                        if ( $detail->reservation_id == $reservation->reservation_id )
                        {
                            $reservation_detail = $detail->name...(or anything)
                        }
                    }
                }


                echo '<tr class="record">'
                . '<td><div align="left">'.$reservation_date.'</div></td>'
                . '<td style="border-left: 1px solid #C1DAD7;">'.$reservation_image.'</td>'
                . '<td>'.$reservation_detail.'</td>'
                .'</tr>';

            }
        }

        ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

and insted of that

```
<a rel="facebox" href="echo site_url('logincon/vieworders'))" id='.$row['reservation_id'].' title="Click To View Orders">View Orders</a>
```

use

```
<?= anchor(site_url('logincon/vieworders'), 'View Orders', 'id='.$row["reservation_id"].' title="Click To View Orders"') ?>
```

edit:

Model

```
<?php

public function getdate()
{
    $q=$this->db->get('orders_date');

    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT field1, field2, date AS field3");

    if ( $q->num_rows() > 0 )
    {
        return $q->result_array();
    }
}

?>
```

View

```
<tbody>
<tr class="record">
        <?php foreach ($date as $da) { ?>
         <td><div align="left"><?php echo $da['field3']; ?></div></td>
        <?php } ?> 
        ...
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: undefined variable:date  <---it gives an output like this

Comment: Im having a problem with the variable date. The name and the quantity were already fine. the 'date' can be found in my table 'reservation'. I already tried this:
     <?= anchor(site_url('logincon/vieworders'), 'View Orders', 'id='.$row["reservation_id"].' title="Click To View Orders"') ?>

Comment: You should use column names same as functions.
If you have to call it table_name.date or SELECT date as variable FROM... then call it $row['variable'] or $row->variable

Comment: i get it. :) 
it is already working but i have a problem again. the order to be shown must in respect with the reservation_id. And in my current state of code, it gives the same output whenever i view the other orders,,,

Comment: Check the edit.

Your tables should same same ID as I showed you above. Otherwise your data will be not synchronized